# How to activate changes changed in constants

Tags: typo3

Sorry, I'm not familiar with typo3... 
I have a typo3 6.2.14 installation (cannot be updated due to needed extensions) where the constants for click-enlarged images had to be adjusted.

I've cleared the cache, but nothing changed. What do I need to do?

```
plugin.tx_kjimagelightbox2.lightBoxMaxW = 1600 //(was 800)
plugin.tx_kjimagelightbox2.lightBoxMaxH = 1200 //(was 600)
```

Nothing changed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wow,

that's some very old TYPO3 with loads of security issues and outdatet PHP as well! Consider forking the extensions and make them work in at least 8.7.

Back to your question.

Where did you set this? Do you use files or do you just edit in the backend? You might need to gather some more information about the order your extensions are beeing loaded.

You might set your values too early and the extensions' defaults overwrite your "changes" (which have actually been declarations)

Maybae you could provide some more information of your setup.

Comment: I've checked contants and setup. Only in Constants there are entries, none in setup. I think that's my problem: I don't know how the extention is being loaded and configured...

Comment: FOUND IT: had to add to constants styles.content.imgtext.linkWrap.width = 0
styles.content.imgtext.linkWrap.height = 0 to reset defaults. Thank you for the hints

Answer (score 0):

the problem is:
the maximum sizes for images can be influenced in multiple places with multiple values.

Even if you have set the correct value, this value may be overwritten later with the smaller values.

1st:
are your original images at least big enough? normaly there is no enlargement of images.

2nd:
inspect the values in the TSOB. Are your values active in the **setup**?
your changes in **constants** may be overwritten in the setup easily and only **setup** is relevant for rendering.

3rd:
there are global maximum values about image rescaling in content elements. maybe these also influence your image rendering in that plugin

Comment: to 1: yes, pics are larger

Comment: to 2: yes, lightbox-values are set + max-imagewidth too

Comment: scambling through the Template analysis I found some static entires whcih might be the problem... Is it correct that they have to be edited via ftp?

Comment: static templates belong to extensions. extension should not be edited in an installation. either change the files in the repository and reapply or use additional typoscript to modify these values. (of course you can edit those files by ftp (or similar like ssh), but that could be problematic if you want to update the installation)